# SQL Server : round and add percent sign

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL query that is returning a result of `92.967013425802` and I need it to be formatted like `93%` and add the percent sign. I have tried changing the sum to round but I received an error

> The function 'round' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause.

My query:

```
select 
    count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over()
from 
    db_table_MetaData
group by 
    MetaValue
order by 
    MetaValue
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend doing the **formatting** in your front end, e.g. your report or web application. SQL Server just stores the **raw data** - it's not SQL Server's job to nicely format it to all imaginable formats...

Comment: [not a valid function?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175003.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
    --Cast(Round(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)), 0) as nvarchar(5) + '%' 
      CAST(Round(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)), 0) as nvarchar(5)) + '%'
from 
    db_table_MetaData
```

This should do the trick.

In essence you take the 08/15 `ROUND()` function to get your numeric value. After this you cast it into a `nvarchar(x)` and add a string to your string. However I have no method of checking my syntax right now.

Comment: I received the following error when running this query. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near +

Comment: I think there was just a paranthesis missing. Updated my answer. If you get an arithemtic overflow, you need to increase the `nvarchar(x)` cast

Answer (score 3):

Strange you got not a valid function.  Perhaps you didn't provide the correct parameters?

This worked for me.

```
select cast(Round('92.967013425802', 0) as nvarchar(10)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the real issue is, but when I tried the below query it worked fine. May be its the placement of parenthesis which went wrong with your query,

```
select 
MetaValue, round(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over(),0)
from db_table_MetaData
group by MetaValue
order by MetaValue
```

check it working at SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55c82/3

Comment: This is working but causing the values to be listed as 3.000000000000 instead of 3.0 How can I adjust the reduce the amount of characters?

Comment: it should have worked as demoed in SQL Fiddle. Still, try round `(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over(),1)`  or
try  `cast(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() + 0.5 as int)` in the `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0):

Answer (count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over(),1)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the FORMAT function with parameter 'p':

```
SELECT FORMAT(50.019/100.0,'p') as [Percentage]
```

This will give you a rounded result like:

```
Percentage
50.02 %
```

Check MSDN for more infos:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh213505.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CONCAT(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)), '%') AS Percentage
from 
    db_table_MetaData
group by 
    MetaValue
order by 
    MetaValue
```

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to offer some explanation of the query, and why you prefer this approach over other answers on this question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26177063)